# does it make sense to talk about サ変名詞{さへんめいし} as 他動詞{たどうし} or 自動詞{じどうし}?

Tags: verbs, particle-を

Does it make sense to talk about サ変名詞 as being 自動詞 or 他動詞? If so, surely some are 他動詞：
車{くるま}を運転{うんてん}する。
日本語{にほんご}を勉強{べんきょう}する。
庭{にわ}を散歩{さんぽ}する。

But, what about 自動詞? Perhaps this [posting of mine from awhile ago](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/12923/does-the-structure%E3%80%8Cverb-stem%E3%81%8C%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B%E3%80%8D-exist) describes 自動詞としてのサ変名詞 (but maybe not)？ More likely, I have insufficient vocab knowledge to think of even one.

And, in a broader context, I am interested in if, in a transitive sentence (regardless of if it is サ変名詞 or not), with a specified direct object, must "を" always be the final 助詞{じょし}?

thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it makes sense to talk about the transitivity of verbal noun plus する constructions.  I would simply link you to the introduction of [*The Light Verb Construction in Japanese: The Role of the Verbal Noun*](http://books.google.com/books?id=CZ86AAAAQBAJ&lpg=PA7&ots=BEQED0j1Kg&hl=ja&pg=PA7#v=onepage&q&f=false), but I suppose it's better if I repeat some of the examples here.  All of the following examples are taken from page 8:

First, intransitive verbal noun + する constructions:

1. 到着する　*arrive*
2. 誕生する　*be born*
3. 死亡する　*die*

Second, transitive verbal noun + する constructions:

1. 警告する　*warn*
2. 破壊する　*destroy*
3. 攻撃する　*attack*

Third, verbal noun + する constructions which can be either transitive or intransitive:

1. 移動する　*move*
2. 破損する　*damage / be damaged*
3. 紛失する　*lose*
4. 縮小する　*shrink / become shrunken*
5. 終了する　*finish*
6. 増加する　*increase*

No, を arguments don't need to be final; they can be scrambled out of their basic position.  Because most constituents in a Japanese sentence are marked (e.g. with case markers like を or postpositions of some kind), sentence order is relatively free, although certain orders may differ in emphasis, and the order isn't *entirely* free.

If you want details about sentence order, I suggest you ask a separate question about it.